# QML Pushbutton with rounded corners

Tags: qt, qml

I am using Creator 4.8.0 and QtQuick 2.9

Is it possible to define in QML a push button that has rounded corners?

Answer (score 2):

QML has a RoundButton with a radius property
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-roundbutton.html

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello Round Button")

    RoundButton {
        text: "Press me please"
        radius: 5
    }
}
```

Comment: RoundButton does not appear in the list of controls in Creator

Comment: did you use the correct import statement for Qt Quick Controls 2? 
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Comment: QtQuick.Controls 2.3 does not appear in the list

Comment: Not sure what "list" you are referring to. I assume you are not using the designer, but you edit the code yourself.  You'll need an import statement in you QML file. It might not be Version 2.3 but rather 2.2 since you are using an older version of QtQuick but it should be there. The RoundButton is around since Qt 5.8. I'll update the answer with some code.

Comment: You can also open up the designer and add a round button form there. It should add all the boilerplate code you'll need to work from there...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Rolf Winter's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816297/7600801

Qt Quick Controls 2.3 was released in Qt 5.10 according to their blogpost:
http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/11/23/ready-qt-quick-controls-2-3/

Using Qt's Maintenance Tool, you should be able to add a 5.10 kit to your installation. Then in your project, add the kit and select it as the kit you want to compile with and you should be able to then import QtQuick.Control 2.3

Comment: That is not necessary. As I wrote in the comment, RoundButton has been around sind Qt 5.8. The OP is using Qt Quick 2.9 which means Qt 5.9. There is no need to update, just to change the import line to the earlier version of Qt Quick Controls (2.2 in that case).